# How is java.util.LinkedList() an instance of MutableList?

Tags: java, kotlin, linked-list, mapped-types, mutablelist

How does the following code compiles without any errors?

```
var linkedList: MutableList<Int> = java.util.LinkedList()
```

when `java.util.LinkedList` class contract clearly doesn't implement the Kotlin interface `MutableList`?

Comment: MutableList is one of the [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types). It maps to Java's List interface.

Comment: Can you write this as an answer? I still cannot get how LinkedList() gets inferred as a MutableList by the compiler by automatically understanding that a LinkedList has write operations.

Comment: If I got the answer right, this question is not dealing with a Java problem, but with a Kotlin feature, right? So why the tag "Java"?

Comment: @Alanpatchi Basically, the Kotlin compiler has some built-in rules that says any `java.util.List` can be _either_ a `kotlin.collections.List` _or_ `kotlin.collections.MutableList`.

Comment: @tquadrat I was not sure if the solution was from the Kotlin features or the Java features before knowing the answer. So I had to tag Java for possible Java reasons as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the compiler isn't inferring anything. *You* are telling the compiler that your `linkedList` variable is to be treated as a `MutableList<Int>`. The compiler allows this because `java.util.LinkedList` is an implementation of the Java `List` interface, which maps to the Kotlin `List` or `MutableList` interfaces.

Per the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types) provided by Tenfour04, a `List<T>` in java is a mapped type which maps to the Kotlin `List<T>` or `MutableList<T>` - the choice is up to you.

Notice that the word *type* is used here, not *class*. What you're doing is simply telling the compiler that you want this variable to be treated as a `MutableList<Int>` - that's it. This idea is reinforced by this sentence in the docs:

> The mapping only matters at compile time, the runtime representation remains unchanged.

So by declaring your variable as mutable or otherwise, you are simply masking the underlying class (java.util.LinkedLink) with a Kotlin mapped type.

We already know that `java.util.LinkedList` is mutable by default. So doing either of these

```
val immutableLinkedList: List<Int> = java.util.LinkedList<Int>()
val mutableLinkedList: MutableList<Int> = java.util.LinkedList<Int>()
```

Is perfectly valid. In the former case, since you've informed the compiler that `immutableLinkedList` is only type `List<Int>` (remember - you can only do this because this Kotlin type maps to a parent type of `LinkedList`), then you will not be able to add to or remove from it, *even though the actual runtime implementation technically allows that*.

These mechanisms are in place to help keep type safety and be explicit about what type of structure you're working with. If you are working in Kotlin, it is *good* to annotate your linkedList as a kotlin type `MutableList`, since it is very clear that this list is in fact mutable.

On there other hand, you could conceivably imagine some situation where the implementation of the list actually mattered, so you may choose to drop the type annotation completely and let the compiler treat it as a `java.util.LinkedList`.

`val myLinkedList = java.util.LinkedList<Int>()`